# Embeding binary framework with cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have `binary framework` which I would like to distribute using `Cocoapods`. I am able to add the `framework` to the project but having trouble linking it.

**here is my podspec:**

```
{
    "name":"myFramework",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "summary":"myFramework", 
    "homepage":"https://.../myFramework",
    "platforms": {
        "ios":"7.0"
    },
    "source": { 
        "http":"https://.../myFramework.zip"
    },
    "requires_arc": true,
    "vendored_frameworks":"myFramework.framework",
    "framework":"myFramework"
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use this podspec for Crashlytics as example: https://github.com/bpoplauschi/CrashlyticsFramework/blob/master/CrashlyticsFramework.podspec

Comment: I have tested the settings from crashlytics but still no luck :(

Comment: Are you seeing build time or run time link errors?

Comment: Running into the same issue. The framework is not linked to the pod so I get a module not found error when trying to use the framework. Any fix to this found?